# How do I deploy my GAE project for only a specific folder?

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

I wonder how do I deploy my Google App Engine project only for a specific folder?

e.g. If my project source folder is "src", and inside this src folder have many sub folders. Say, I have css, app, images, and js folders, but I want to deploy only css, app and images folders to the GAE, I want GAE to ignore js folder during the deployment, is there any way to do so with some setting in app.yaml file?

Thanks!

Joel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at `skip_files`

[Skipping Files](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Skipping_Files)

> Files in your application directory whose paths match a static_dir path or a static_files upload path are considered to be static files. All other files in the application directory are considered to be application program and data files.
>
> The skip_files element specifies which files in the application
>   directory are not to be uploaded to App Engine. The value is either a
>   regular expression, or a list of regular expressions. Any filename
>   that matches any of the regular expression is omitted from the list of
>   files to upload when the application is uploaded.

Comment: @JoelT. be aware that by using `skip_files` it does replace the whole app you deployed previously. so if you uploaded javascript files in your js folder to the app and then you use skip_files you won't have them online any more.

Comment: @aschmid00. Thanks! In fact I use skip_file mainly for my backup folders, such as js_bac, not exactly the working folder js. Anyway thanks for the advice! :)

Comment: great. Feel free to accept the answer if it was what you were looking for :) it also helps others who can then see this as answered.

Comment: It's not a great solution though; how can we target just one directory for example?

Comment: if it's a regex (and it's been a while!) then you can use that to filter in/out things as well by including the path in the regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can now add a `.gcloudignore` file to the root of your project (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore). The syntax is the same as `.gitignore` files.

For the OPs case, placing the following in the root folder (next to `app.yaml`) should do the trick:

```
# .gcloudignore

src/js/
```